# Vuetify outline labels looking odd after the latest update

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently using 2.5 and all my outlined fields now have the label too close to the top:
[image]

Apparently, the reason is the code below:

```
.v-text-field--outlined .v-label--active {
transform: translateY(-24px) scale(.75);}
```

If I disable that using the chrome tools, then the following CSS will be used, which makes the label looks ok:

```
.v-text-field .v-label--active {
    max-width: 133%;
    transform: translateY(-18px) scale(.75);
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[image]

I just want to understand if I'm suppoused to specify any special attribute:

```
 <v-col cols="12" sm="8" class="text-center">
     <ValidationProvider vid="company_cif" name=" " rules="required|max:20" v-slot="{ errors, valid }">
        <v-text-field v-model="current.company.tin" maxlength="20" :label="$t('company.tin')" outlined append-icon="mdi-passport" persistent-hint :error-messages="errors" :readonly="!rights" @change="passes(updateCompanyCheck)"></v-text-field>
     </ValidationProvider>
 </v-col>
```

Comment: actually, the active label is supposed to overlap the top border. and it always was. maybe you customised it and now their updates conflict with your css rules?

Comment: Really? I've been looking to my custom css but couldn't see any rule there @IgorMoraru - the first one looks ok to you? No padding at all on the top looks odd to me

Comment: look at this example: https://codepen.io/bgtor/pen/wvJdjJe .  It looks like none of your inputs (same apply to the example on vuetify site). In active state the label is overlaping the border (sort of 'inline' with the border). I have no other explanation why in your code it looks different (I don't believe in magic :)

Comment: Use the Computed Styles panel in DevTools to determine the source of that style. It's probably caused by your app's own styles.